# Transaction-per-session or transaction-per-query pattern in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, exception, transactions, rollback

We have a servlet to serve many concurrent requests and sometimes some request throw exceptions. I saw this warning from Hibernate guide:

> "If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance."

In my real scenario, a request has made many important changes to DB and when we caught an exception, we must rollback all changes have made before.

So it seems we must implement the transaction-per-request pattern instead transaction-per-query to sure all changes are going to be rolled back.

It's right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want, but yes, in general, you want one transaction for the life of a request, and you want all db operations for that request to participate in that one transaction.  Usually, this also means there is one session bound to the request.

Comment: How about this pattern performance and scalable in concurrency environment? I see we'll have many queries per transaction. But the Hibernate guide says: 
"In order to reduce lock contention in the database, a database transaction has to be as short as possible."